# Why No Lifejacket Badge?

Tags: support, bug, badges

I noticed that the requirement for the Lifejacket badge appear to have been met for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509859/6689725) (score +9/-1) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59509764/6689725) (score +9/-3). The [vote aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59509764/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries#voteaggregate_637131743999999999) shows all of the downvotes on the question were received on the same day it was asked, and before it received any upvotes.

> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more.

The only thing I can guess is that perhaps I submitted the answer *before* the question received the second downvote, making it forever ineligible for this badge? I hope that isn't the case since it seems contrary to the purpose of the badge, but I'm only speculating at this point.

Comment: _"...since it seems contrary to the purpose of the badge"_ It's not. Say you answered a question when it had a score of 0/0, then it received two downvotes, and then later received 4+ upvotes (and your answer reached a score of 5+ at some point). Now, the question did have a score of -2 and it did reach a score of +2 but your answer didn't exactly cause the reversal of the score (which is the point of the badge).

Comment: @41686d6564 That's like saying "You don't get this lifeguard award for saving that drowning kid because you tossed the life jacket to him *too soon*, maybe you should have let him flounder for a while longer"

Comment: @Z4-tier Well, yes, it is saying that. A good lifeguard doesn't go around tossing life jackets to every swimmer who shows the slightest trouble swimming. The swimmer needs to be having some serious trouble before a life jacket should be tossed to them :)

Comment: @cigien like most analogies, this one only goes so far before it breaks down. I wish I could see timestamps on downvotes, because I think they were all cast almost at the same time I posted my answer (with the exception of one, which was cast by some crank on the same day I posted this question on meta). At any rate, I still think the intended purpose of the badge was satisfied. There should be a short window *after* an answer is posted during which any downvotes received by the question still apply for the purposes of awarding this badge.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is right, according to the [triggering criteria](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat) for the Lifejacket badge

> A user posted an answer to a question with a score of <= -2 **at the time**

(*emphasis mine*)

So you can't earn the badge for your answer since you posted it when the question score was -1.

Comment: So.. one has to first downvote the Question, post an Answer, then undownvote it and hope some other people come along to upvote it? :)

Comment: @Scratte I know you're not seriously suggesting it, but from the same section that I quoted, one of the rules is "*Don’t count the user’s votes on the question*", so that trick wouldn't work anyway :)

Comment: I was joking. I just figured someone else would be thinking it too :)

Comment: And I guess undeleting an answer doesn’t count as posting either?

Comment: @user3840170 I'm not entirely sure, but my guess is that yes, undeleting doesn't count as posting.